# How to generate content on ejs with jquery after ajax call to express server

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, ejs

I want to implement a search feature on my website so what i do is make a jquery ajax call with the text to the express server which searches mongodb and gives an object array of the users that match. Now i receive this object succesfully but since there are no partials on ejs how can i refresh just the results list generating the html for each user?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The node EJS packages comes with a client-side javascript library located in `./node_modules/ejs/ejs.js` or `./node_modules/ejs/ejs.min.js`. After you include this on your page, you'll want to load the template, then generate the HTML from the template.
[Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property?rq=1)
Javascript Sample (loading the template on page load would be a bit more ideal):

```
function getData() {
    // Grab the template
    $.get('/results.ejs', function (template) {
        // Compile the EJS template.
        var func = ejs.compile(template);

        // Grab the data
        $.get('/data', function (data) {
           // Generate the html from the given data.
           var html = func(data);
           $('#divResults').html(html);
        });
    });
}
```

EJS:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Name</th>
    </tr>   
    <% data.forEach(function (d) { %>
    <tr>
        <td><%- d.id %></td>
        <td><%- d.name %></td>
    </tr>
    <% }); %>
</table>
```

Ajax call in express:

```
app.get('/data', function (req, res) {
    res.send({ data: [
        { id: 5, name: 'Bill' },
        { id: 1, name: 'Bob' }
    ]});
});
```

Comment: Can you place the `getData` function inside the template itself or you'll have to create an external `script` file containing the function that you'll then inject inside your page?

Comment: @AllJs, As far as I know you can place it within the script, however, I think it would be better organized if you had an external script file.