# Posting to Node js using javascript and displaying the output on the html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I am trying to send some values via a `POST` method to a `node.js` method.
The `node.js` will return an output based on the result and I need to update the HTML.
I am making use of `ejs` to communicate back with the HTML. I need to make use of the Javescript method as I will be using it to customize the UI based on the output I received after executing the Node JS method.

**HTML**

```
<form id="form-register"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <input type="logintext" value="" name="nam" class="nameC" id="mc" > 

   <input type="submit" name="subscribe" onclick="myFunction()" id="mc-submit-number">

   <label  >REEEEE <%= titles %></label>

</form>
```

**JAVASCRIPT METHOD**

```
function myFunction() {
  $("#mc-form-register").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //Prevents the page from refreshing

    var $this = $(this);
    $.post("http://localhost:8081/ttt",
      $this.serialize(), // Serializes form data in standard format

      function(data, status) { /** code to handle response **/
        alert('Hey ' + data.titles + ' ' + status);
      },
      "json" // The format the response should be in
    );
  });
}
```

**NODE JS**

```
app.post('/ttt', function (req,res){

loginProvider.signUp(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {

      res.render('index',{title: 'HOME',titles:err.stack
      });
    }
    else   {
      res.render('index',{title: 'HOME',titles:'SUCCESS'
      });

    }  

});

}
```

Comment: You should return a json object from your post route, based on which you can generate the html or do whatever you want in your ajax success callback.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it. I am a newbie.

Comment: What is the exact problem you are facing? Are you getting any error in console with above code, if yes specify it in the question

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18935597/how-to-generate-content-on-ejs-with-jquery-after-ajax-call-to-express-server

Comment: @anu No errors in the console. The data is just not displaying.

Comment: Any recommendations ?